# how to display Quiz randomly and without duplication in react native

Tags: typescript, react-native, random, visual-studio-code

everyone.
I try to make Quiz app  randomly and without duplication in React Native .
Successfully Quiz are displayed randomly.
But I don't know how to display them without duplication .
I am very new to learn React Native.
If you have any idea to solve this issue , please help me .
I use Mac book pro , Visual Code Studio and React Native.

I write the code as below .

```
export function App() {

 const questions = [

  {
   questionText: "city",
  answerOptions: [
  { answerText: "canada", isCorrect: false },
  { answerText: "USA", isCorrect: false },
  { answerText: "Napoli", isCorrect: true },
  { answerText: "Brazil", isCorrect: false },
  ],

  },


 {
 questionText: "country",
 answerOptions: [
 { answerText: "Paris", isCorrect: false },
 { answerText: "London", isCorrect: false },
 { answerText: "Spain", isCorrect: true },
 { answerText: "Rome", isCorrect: false },
 ],
 },


 {
 questionText: "color",
 answerOptions: [
 { answerText: "dog", isCorrect: false },
 { answerText: "cat", isCorrect: false },
 { answerText: "blue", isCorrect: true },
 { answerText: "tiger", isCorrect: false },
 ],
 },


 {
 questionText: "currency",
 answerOptions: [
 { answerText: "cash", isCorrect: false },
 { answerText: "money", isCorrect: false },
 { answerText: "Pond", isCorrect: true },
 { answerText: "card", isCorrect: false },
 ],
 },
 ];



 const randomQuestions =
 questions[Math.floor(Math.random() * questions.length)];

 return (
 <View style={styles.container}>

<Text style={styles.question}>
{randomQuestions.questionText}
</Text>



<Text style={styles.answer}>
{randomQuestions.answerOptions[0].answerText}
</Text>

<Text style={styles.answer}>
{randomQuestions.answerOptions[1].answerText}
</Text>

<Text style={styles.answer}>
{randomQuestions.answerOptions[2].answerText}
</Text>

<Text style={styles.answer}>
{randomQuestions.answerOptions[3].answerText}
</Text>

</View>
);

};
```

Comment: You may have received downvotes since by using React Native, it could be assumeed you have some decent prior experience with programming, however the solution here is likely something which could be found out through some basic research / tutorials :) If you don't have much programming experience, then it might be worth learning with something simpler

Answer (score 0):

Each time a question is asked, remove it from the possible next question list.

If your intention is to present all the questions in a random order, just shuffle the question array before you start.  See eg. [w3docs js array shuffle](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array.html)

Comment: thank you for the comment .
Do you mean using .splice() ?

I tried to make empty array like [] and push random number if the number doesn't exit in the array . 
If there is same number in array , I use splice() to remove it from array .

Comment: You don't think it's the answer to your question?

Comment: this is the code I tried as below .
But it didn't work 

const randomQuiz: number[] = []; 
const min = 0;
const max = questions.length;

function intRandom(min: number, max: number) {
return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

for (let i = min; i < max; i++) {
while (true) {
let tmp = intRandom(min, max); 
if (!randomQuestions.includes(tmp)) {
randomQuestions.push(tmp);
randomQuestions.splice(tmp);
break;
}
}
}

Comment: >You don't think it's the answer to your question?

Can I ask you which code means "Each time a question is asked" ? 
I'm confused a bit .

Comment: The code you show, is used to present one question with its answers, I believe.  The next time this code runs, the previous question should have been removed from the list of questions.